# (Docker+SpringBoot+Mysql) Mysql connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker

**Problem Description**

Spring Boot(app) container cant connect to "mysql" container

**Problem Output**

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3 times. Giving up.

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/fms?autoReconnect=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.password = manager@123
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.7'
services:  
    mysql:
        image: mysql:latest
        restart: always
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        ports:
            - "33061:3306"
        networks:
            - spring-boot-mysql-network
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: fms
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: manager@123
        volumes:
            - ./database_storage:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

    app:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: app.Dockerfile
        ports: 
            - "8091:8080"
        networks:
            - spring-boot-mysql-network
        depends_on: 
            - mysql

    phpmyadmin:
        image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
        container_name: phpmyadmin
        restart: always
        depends_on: 
            - mysql
        environment: 
            PMA_HOST: database
            PMA_PORT: 3306
        ports:
            - "9091:80"

networks:
    spring-boot-mysql-network:
        driver: bridge
```

Comment: Try `"3306:3306"` rather than `"33061:3306"` or use `33061` as the port number on `jdbc:mysql://mysql:33061.......`

Comment: Thank for you reply :) But I have tried both  of your solutions.It still says "Connection refused"

Comment: Is the container with MySQL started? Is MySQL started within the container? Is there a firewall getting in the way?

Comment: yes.docker ps shows status (up 3 minutes)

Comment: I can even connect 'mysql container' using its ip from my hostmachine by(mysql -h 192.168.32.2 -P 3306 -u root -p)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had done a silly mistake.

> I was updating my application.property file and docker-compose up
>   --build.But I never repackaged war file.So I was reading my old war file and thus reading my old property file

Comment: Is insaan ko 100 kaude maare jaye. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your settings look correct to me. However, you are using the latest docker image of MySQL (which is 8.0.x at the time of writing). So, the exception you got indicates that there is a compatibility issue between your MySQL connector and MySQL server version. Which version of [MySQL Connector/J](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) are you using in your Spring Boot application? You need to update the connector or downgrade the MySQL docker image version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) I have used 5.1.45 version of MYSQL Connector. I have just tried by replacing 'latest' with 5.7 . But no success. Can you suggest any further suggestions?

Comment: @Dipesh sorry, I provided the wrong link. I meant the latest version of MySQL Connector/J, which is `8.0.19` (I fixed the link now). MySQL docker version is OK, you can leave it at `latest`, but it'ld be better if you also set the exact docker version, e.g. `mysql:8.0`.

Comment: Even with the use of mysql:8.0 and connector:8.0.19 , connection is refused :(

Comment: @Dipesh could you provide the whole exception log please? Also please provide your hibernate settings if you've set any.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try updating mysql connector version to `mysql-connector-java-8.0.11`

Comment: Thanks for reply . I have updated mysql-connector to 8.0.11 just as you said. But still connection is refused